# Angular move array items between arrays on click - Plunkr included

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angular5

I'm looking to create a list of tags, when you click the blue tag it gets added to a new array and is displayed above, it should be unselectable in the old array but its place is marked by css however the user should be able to click it in the new array and it will go back to its original place in the old array and be removed from the new array. I've made [a plunker with what I have done so far](https://embed.plnkr.co/Vr2hWRrCCb8NWHbBGznR/).

So far the issue is that when clicked it gets added to the new array but it is still clickable in the old array, so clicking it multiple times ends up adding duplicate values to the new array, I also need functionality where if the user clicks it in the new array it goes back to its original spot in the old array.

and here is the typescript code for anyone who wants to view it here

```typescript
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <div>
          <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
        </div>

        <p>
        Current behaviour: user clicks the blue tag and it goes into the array displayed above.
        user clicks already selected blue tag and it duplicated in array. wanted behaviour is that once selected
        it goes into the new array and it is then unclickable in the blue tags part, but you can click it from the above part and
        it will be visible and selectable in the blue part again
        </p>


        <p>
        TLDR: click blue tag and goes into another array, click tag in new array and it goes back to the blue array
        </p>

        <ul>
              <li>
                <div class="c-seedContainer u-displayOnly">
                  <span *ngFor="let m of matchArray; let i = index">{{ m }}</span> 
                </div>  
              </li>         
              <li>
                <div class="c-seedContainer u-selectionSeed">
                  <span  [class.u-removeSeed]="stateOfButton[i]" (click)="changeState(i,c)" *ngFor="let c of cloneSeedArrayForSelection; let i = index">{{ c }}</span> 
                </div>  
              </li>     
        </ul>
      `,
    })
    export class App {
      name:string;

    seed: Array<any> = [
        "ice",
        "hockey",
        "rubbish",
        "traitor",
        "mneumonic",
        "chronical",
        "stuff",
        "entity",
        "poo",
        "junk",
        "mcDonalds",
        "Fruit",
        "going",
        "sweet"
      ]

        cloneSeedArray: Array<any> = [];
        cloneSeedArrayForSelection: Array<any> = [];    

        selectedIdx = 0;
        stateOfButton: boolean[];

        matchArray: Array<any> = [];   

      constructor() {
        this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
      }

      changeState(index, seedWord) {

        // a) click item to add / remove a class
        // b) add item to a new array
        // c) compare both arrays to ensure they match   
        // d) if both arrays dont match show warning and allow to recreate 
        // this.selectedIdx = index;
        console.log("index " + index)
        this.matchArray.push(seedWord)
        this.stateOfButton[index] = !this.stateOfButton[index];
        console.log("seedWord " + seedWord)    
      }   

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.cloneSeedArray = this.seed.slice();  
      this.cloneSeedArrayForSelection = this.shuffleArray( this.cloneSeedArray  )
      this.stateOfButton = Array(this.cloneSeedArrayForSelection.length).fill(false);  
      this.cd.detectChanges();
    }

    shuffleArray(d) {
        for ( let  c = d.length - 1; c > 0; c--) {
            let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * (c + 1));
            let a = d[c];
            d[c] = d[b];
            d[b] = a;
        }
        return d
    };
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [ BrowserModule ],
    declarations: [ App ],
    bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Please add some code to your question

Comment: I added a plunkr

Comment: `this.cd.detectChanges();` this line is not working because cd is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would map your array to array of objects with `selected` property.

This way way we can easily determine which element should be displayed in new array and which should remain in old array

**ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  seed = [
    "ice",
    ...
  ];

  items: Item[];
  selectedItems: Item[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = this.shuffleArray(this.seed)
      .map(x => ({ name: x, selected: false }));
  }

  select(item: Item) {
    if (item.selected) {
      return;
    }

    this.selectedItems.push(item);
    item.selected = true;
  }

  unSelect(item: Item, idx: number) {
    item.selected = false;
    this.selectedItems.splice(idx, 1);
  }

 ...
}

interface Item {
  name: string;
  selected: boolean;
}
```

**html**

```
<li>
  <div class="c-seedContainer u-displayOnly">
    <span *ngFor="let item of selectedItems; let i = index" (click)="unSelect(item, i)">
     {{ item.name }}
    </span> 
  </div>  
</li>         
<li>
  <div class="c-seedContainer u-selectionSeed">
    <span [class.u-removeSeed]="item.selected" (click)="select(item)" 
                        *ngFor="let item of items">
      {{ item.name }}
    </span> 
  </div>
</li>
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/F5FxABvidVB4RiMBitpu)**

**Note:** I also removed `pointer-events: none;` rule from `.c-seedContainer.u-displayOnly` selector in your css

Comment: any idea how i can compare the items array to the seed array to see if they are in the right order ? the plan is that when the user selects the last blue tag that it will check both arrays to see if they are in the same order and if not it will show an error

Comment: @Kravitz I updated example https://ng-run.com/edit/F5FxABvidVB4RiMBitpu

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following code lines to the "changeState" method to know if the word is already in the array

```
changeState(index, seedWord) {

// a) click item to add / remove a class
// b) add item to a new array
// c) compare both arrays to ensure they match   
// d) if both arrays dont match show warning and allow to recreate 
// this.selectedIdx = index;
for(let word of this.matchArray){
  if(word == seedWord){
    return;
  }
}
console.log("index " + index)
this.matchArray.push(seedWord)
this.stateOfButton[index] = !this.stateOfButton[index];
console.log("seedWord " + seedWord)}
```